# Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, linux, server, command, port

I try to install a java HTTP API on my linux server. I try to execute this command from command pompt to run the service:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -cp .:boilerpipe-1.2.0.jar:lib/nekohtml-1.9.13.jar:lib/xerces-2.9.1.jar:lib/langdetect.jar:lib/jsonic-1.2.8.jar ExampleProgram
```

Then I have this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>           at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.(ServerImpl.java:100)
>           at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
>           at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
>           at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:129)
>           at ExampleProgram.main(ExampleProgram.java:37)

Here is ExampleProgram.java:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import de.l3s.boilerpipe.document.TextDocument;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput;


// Language detect librarys
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.*;

import net.arnx.jsonic.JSON;
import net.arnx.jsonic.JSONException;


import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

class ExampleProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

EveryDetector evr = new EveryDetector();
InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",8080);
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(addr, 0);

MyHandler hndl = new MyHandler();
hndl.setDetector(evr);

MyHandlerExtractContent hnd2 = new MyHandlerExtractContent();
hnd2.setDetector(evr);

MyHandlerDetectLanguage hnd3 = new MyHandlerDetectLanguage();
hnd3.setDetector(evr);

server.createContext("/",hndl);
server.createContext("/extractcontent",hnd2);
server.createContext("/detectlanguage",hnd3);
server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
server.start();
System.out.println("Server is listening on port 8080" );


 }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/remdex/boilerpipe-and-language-detect-api-server

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What looks like is happening is that something is already running on port 8080 if you change the port number your problem should go away.

Comment: I thought what you said but I do not have much knowledge about this. How can I change it to a different port?

Comment: in this line `InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",8080);` this is where you set the port to 8080 change that number to 9090. Also something worth noting when you access it youll have to type in localhost:9090 in your address bar

Comment: I can do this but should I execute other transaction? To create port for 9090?

Comment: What do you mean by execute other transaction? What line would that be?

Comment: No problem I'm glad i could help